# Adding markers before and after text selection (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want add markers before and after selected text in `div` such as, for example, ios do:

[image]

With this markers user should to continue selection if necessary.   How can I do this with jquery? Selected text I'm getting with this js script.

```js
document.onmouseup = function() {
      
   if (window.getSelection) {
        
  text = window.getSelection().toString();
    alert(text);
    
 } 
  
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```